# What is the purpose of listen() in Socket Programming?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp, listen

`ret = listen(connection_socket, 1);`  //allowing one connection in queue

I have opened 2 terminals and ran client process in all 2 terminals at the same time.

Here server is busy in processing client1 data, now client2 is in pending queue. Now queue is full.

At this stage, i have launched 3rd terminal and ran client process. Sine queue is full, connect for this client should return -1 and errno should set to ECONNREFUSED,
but in this case, connect is returning 0 for client 3 too. Then what is the purpose of `listen()` system call.

Comment: It seems the "or" clause of the [`listen` documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/listen.2.html) may provide the hint you're looking for.

Answer (score 9):

`listen` tells the TCP/IP stack to start accept incoming TCP connections on the port the socket is binded to.

The backlog parameter is not a "maximum number of connections allowed" parameter. Rather it's just a hint to the stack about how many TCP connections can be accepted on the socket's port before the applicaiton code has invoked `accept` on that socket.  Be aware that `accept` doesn't negotiate a TCP handshake, it just takes one of the already accepted connections out of the backlog queue (or waits for one to arrive).

So if your backlog is 1 and your server thread isn't waiting on `accept`, than means that an incoming client connection will at least establish the TCP handshake.  If you attempt to have two pending connections when the backlog queue is 1, the second client connection will likely timeout or be refused if the server code isn't actively invoking `accept` to promote those connections out of the backlog and into sockets.

Comment: As, OP's server has not yet accepted the connection, yet clients connect has succeeded. 
what will happen to the immediate write on that socket.

Comment: It will be the same as a server that hasn't called "read" or "recv".  Eventually, the sliding window will collapse to zero such that no further transmissions occur until the server has dequeued the data.

Comment: THis seems like a big drawback, as on server, buffer is getting allocated, if OP starts more such clients, it could cause severe memory shortage on server.

Comment: @RootPhoenix - **that's literally the whole point of the second parameter to `listen`.**   See answer above.